# Arm-based meta-analysis of variation and mean with interval scale data

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression, metafor

I’ve been extracting data for an arm-based meta-analysis on the distribution of a self-report survey in various research contexts. I am interested in the approach taken in Nagakawa et al. (2015), example 3, in that I would like to look at whether the variance of the survey changes, as well as whether the means change. As my approach is arm-based (most papers only feature a single context, and I’m use robust variance estimators to take into account papers with multiple contexts), I was planning to use log(SD) as the outcome for the variance analysis using measure = "SDLN" in metafor’s escalc and raw means for the means using measure = “MN”, since the survey is always reported on the same scale. One of the steps that Nagakawa et al. (2015) outline in their paper is that one needs to check whether there is a relationship between the variance and the mean in the dataset. Since their paper is focused on introducing variance meta-analysis, they introduce this check in the context of a log(SD) model. They note that when data is ratio scale, one uses log(mean) as the predictor, but if the data is interval (as is the case with self-report survey data) one can use the raw sample means as a predictor (Nagakawa et al. 2015, p. 148). I checked the scatterplot of log(SD) and mean and it looks like there is the typical positive relationship. It looks linear, homoscedastic and comes out as significant in a baseline model – so ok to proceed with correcting for the sample means in my meta-regression model of log(SD) and reporting moderator effects correcting for mean. For reference, my baseline model for log(SD) using metafor/clubSandwich looks like:

```
baseline_lnSD<-rma.mv(yi = lnSD, V = V_mat_lnSD,
       mods = ~scale(M),
       random = list(~ 1 | Paper_ID/ effect_ID), 
       data = dat_total)
conf_int(baseline_lnSD,vcov="CR2")
```

My question here relates to how to best incorporate my knowledge of the mean-variance relationship into the meta-regression models for the means. One tutorial paper I’ve seen applies the arm-based meta-analysis approach using data on a ratio scale, so their model of the mean used log(mean) as the DV, and they demonstrated two specifications of the model (Senior et al., 2016). They say that if you choose not to correct for the mean-variance relationship by using log(SD) as a predictor, this would be an effect size similar to log(response ratio) and that if you wanted to correct for the relationship, you can use log(SD) as a predictor, which “becomes  similar  to  using  a standardized  mean  difference  such  as  Hedge’s d,  although  it  should  be  noted  this  is  on  a  log scale” (Senior et al., 2016, p 250). However, since my outcome is interval scale rather than ratio scale, I’m not sure how to enter variance as a predictor to get an effect size that is easily interpretable? For example, if I just switched the variables of my log(SD) model around to get:

```
baseline_M<-rma.mv(yi = M, V = V_mat_M,
       mods = ~scale(lnSD),                    
       random = list(~ 1 |  Paper_ID/ effect_ID), 
       data = dat_total)
conf_int(baseline_M,vcov="CR2")
```

then I have a meta-analytic estimate of the mean while correcting for log(SD) and my coefficients for moderators in my other meta-regression models would be interpreted as the effect of the moderator while correcting for log(SD). I can’t tell if there is anything wrong with this model specification apart from my finding it unintuitive. In my mind, it’s preferable from a workflow and communication perspective to keep the variables on the same scale as I switch between which of mean or variance is the dependent variable in the model, but perhaps using raw SD as the predictor in the raw mean models is easier to explain in this context? Is it correct that using raw SD would also get me something like Hedge’s d in interpretation?

As noted in this other post I found here ([R Metafor Measure = MN](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/517529/r-metafor-measure-mn)), there don’t seem to be many examples of raw means analysis for arm-based models, so I’m not sure how the mean-variance relationship should be accounted for. Thanks in advance for any advice!

References:

Nakagawa, S., Poulin, R., Mengersen, K., Reinhold, K., Engqvist, L., Lagisz, M., & Senior, A. M. (2015). Meta‐analysis of variation: ecological and evolutionary applications and beyond. Methods in Ecology and Evolution, 6(2), 143-152.

Senior, A. M., Gosby, A. K., Lu, J., Simpson, S. J., & Raubenheimer, D. (2016). Meta-analysis of variance: an illustration comparing the effects of two dietary interventions on variability in weight. Evolution, medicine, and public health, 2016(1), 244-255.

Comment: You might have better luck posting on the mailing list for meta-aanlysis in R https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// Please provide a link there to this post as cross-posting is deprecated.